Right matrix division in NumPy, any better way than np.linalg.inv()?
What is the fastest way of doing right matrix division, i.e. xA = B in pyhton numpy? A and B are (NxN) square matrices and A is invertible, I thus want to compute equation x = BA^{-1}.
I am asking because for the left matrix division , Ax = B, x = A^{-1}B, using x = np.linalg.solve(A,B) is preferred to x = np.linalg.inv(A) @ B because of speed reasons.
But I have not found a way how to do this for the right matrix division. Right now I use x = B @ np.linalg.inv(A) Is there any better (= faster) way of doing this?

The fastest way to solve Ax = B is not to do a division at all, but to use solvers. Divisions are generally very slow and inefficient for this.

The 'problem' with using inv is that it is usually performed by doing solve(A,I).

Simply use numpy.linalg.solve to solve the transposed equation A.T x.T = B.T:
x = np.linalg.solve(A.T, B.T).T


Oh thank you very much! I did not see how that followed from xA=B before.

On my computer, 20secs your current method, 13 seconds the scipy:
import numpy as np
import datetime
from scipy.linalg import solve

A = np.random.rand(10000, 10000)
B = np.random.rand(10000, 10000)

#Your currrent method
print(datetime.datetime.now())
x = B @ np.linalg.inv(A)
print(datetime.datetime.now())

#From scipy
print(datetime.datetime.now())
x = solve(A, B)
print(datetime.datetime.now())


You're solving the wrong equation, Ax=B instead of xA=B.

@user2357112, yes, those two are not equivalent because of how matrix multiplication works (Ax is not equal to xA)
